# Magit cannot find locally installed git version

Tags: git, emacs, spacemacs, tramp, magit

I am trying to use Magit and TRAMP together in order to access git repositories on a server from a macOS laptop.

The server has git 1.7.12 as default, which is below the required version by Magit. I have installed git 2.9.5 to `/my/local/path/bin` I can check this by typing `git --version` using `M-x shell` via TRAMP the output is 2.9.5 as expected. The remote shell is `zsh` and the relevant local path is being set in `.profile`.

---

So as suggested at:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/37886703/3228006

I add the following to my dotspacemacs/user-config:

```
(require 'tramp)
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path "/my/local/path/bin")
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path 'tramp-own-remote-path)
```

I then delete `.emacs.d/.cache/tramp` as suggested in the manual so that tramp does not attempt to reuse an old connection, and load spacemacs. I am greeted with:

```
1 error(s) on startup! Spacemacs may not be able to operate properly.
```

I use `emacs --debug-init` to find the cause

```
Error in dotspacemacs/user-config: Symbol's value as variable is void: path
```

---

Commenting out the lines I added removes the error which suggests to me that `'tramp-remote-path` is void. This should not be the case as far as what I expected, especially since I added `(require 'tramp)` to be certain that tramp was loaded before accessing the remote path variable.

Removing `require 'tramp` does not solve the problem. Removing all three lines and doing `C-h v 'tramp-remote-path` outputs (before doing anything with tramp whatsoever):

```
(tramp-default-remote-path "/bin" "/usr/bin" "/sbin" "/usr/sbin" "/usr/local/bin" "/usr/local/sbin" "/local/bin" "/local/freeware/bin" "/local/gnu/bin" "/usr/freeware/bin" "/usr/pkg/bin" "/usr/contrib/bin" "/opt/bin" "/opt/sbin" "/opt/local/bin")
```

This is confusing as it seems to indicate that on startup the variable in question is *not* void. Furthermore, I have a version of emacs and spacemacs compiled up on the server, if I login and use magit there it finds my locally installed version of git no problem and everything works as expected.

---

If anyone is able to help debug further it would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a typo in my /.spacemacs the error I pasted above looked dodgy to me and I realised the line:

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path "/my/local/path/bin")
```

Was actually written as:

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote path "/my/local/path/bin")
```

Note the space between remote and path. Now that this is fixed deleting the cache again and reloading has fixed the issue.